# When a map is copied to another existing map, what happend in details?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, swap, stdmap

```
int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> foo,bar;

  foo['x']=100;
  foo['y']=200;
  foo['z']=300;

  bar['x']=100;
  bar['y']=2000;
  bar['zz']=400;

  foo=bar;
  return 0;
}
```

Is it such a process that foo clear all its elements and then traverse bar to construct its new elements?
Or foo traverse all the keys of foo and bar and then execute only necessary modification?
I encountered such a situation that access to a map by key can't work for a short time. And the reason may be that the map was being updated using the "=" assignment (foo=bar).
Is it possible to solve this problem by using std::swap (foo.swap(bar))?
Or a read-write lock must be used?

Comment: Modifying `map` is not atomic (even with swap), so in multithreading case, you have to protect the change (mutex, ...).

Comment: Assignment isn't thread-safe, if that's what you're wondering. You need an atomic map, or doing an atomic swap, or using a lock to solve it. (And note that the `swap` member function or the `std::swap` specialization is not marked as atomic or thread-safe in the C++ specification.)

Comment: You're calling std::map::operator=, so here is the documentation for that function:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator%3D

Comment: "I encountered such a situation that the access to a map by key can't work for a short time" are we talking about multithreading? If not it isnt clear what you mean, if it is you should show the code that has the problem, because the code you did post has none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it such a process that foo clear all it's elements and then traverse bar to construct it's new elements? Or foo traverse all the keys of foo and bar and then execute only necessary modification?

What your doing there is a copy assign. Meaning that first the `foo` will be cleared and then the elements in `bar` will be copied to it.

> I encountered such a situation that the access to a map by key can't work for a short time.

I'm assuming that your multithreading and that's why your having that issue. As *@Jarod42* and *@Some programmer dude* stated, assignment or modifying a map is not thread safe, meaning that the resources must be locked prior to modifying it. You can do this using a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

> Is it possible to solve this problem by using std::swap (foo.swap(bar))?

The specification does not say anything about it being thread safe so its best advised to make sure that the resources are locked before swapping.

Also note that your not only assigning the values from `bar` to `foo` when using `std::map<,>::swap` or `std::swap`, your also altering `bar` by assigning `foo`'s values to it. Its not the same as `foo = bar;`.

Additional: [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)